# Parent Component re-render mutiple times in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

i want to send a request to the server when the user reach to bottom of page, i'm tring to send some addition data to the server as limit and skip, i called `scrollNo` (it is a state) and `POSTS_PER_SCROLL` (it is a normal value), my problom is when i want to send the requset to the server, `scrollNo` change multiple times (multiple re-render) in this component (parent), how can i avoid these multi rendering to prevent multiple request?

```
const POSTS_PER_SCROLL = 6;

const Posts = () => {
  const [scrollNo, setScrollNo] = useState(1);
  const [transitionData] = useHttp();
  const [posts, getPosts] = usePosts();
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { getPsts } = useContext(PostContext);

  const getAllPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const responseData = await transitionData(
        `http://localhost:5000/post/${authContext.userId}/posts?quantity=${POSTS_PER_SCROLL}&scrollNo=${scrollNo}`
      );

      getPosts(responseData);  // change the state
      getPsts(responseData);  // change the state
    } catch (error) {}
  }, [transitionData, authContext.userId, getPosts, getPsts, scrollNo]);

  useEffect(() => {  // this useEffect runs after initilize the component (just once)
    (async () => {
      if (
        authContext.userId &&
        authContext.token &&
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(posts).length === 0
      ) {
        try {
          await getAllPosts();
        } catch (error) {}
      }
    })();
  }, [authContext.userId, authContext.token, getAllPosts, posts]);

  useEffect(() => {  // this useEffect runs by scrolling (every time reach to bottom of page)
    const scrollToGetPosts = async () => {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        setScrollNo(prevState => prevState + 1);  // change the state when the user reach to bottom of page

        try {
          await getAllPosts();
        } catch (error) {}
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollToGetPosts);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollToGetPosts);
  }, [getAllPosts]);
};

export default Posts;
```

in the console:

[image]

Comment: Why do you use the useEffect by scrolling? I think, it is better to save the scroll position as a state of the component.

Comment: In addition to @PeterPark comment, why you have `useEffect ` twice? you can add it to one. and I think it rerenders because 4 `useSate`, any change in `useSate` it will rerender the component, so think on adding it to one state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14271386/peter-park Beacuse if the user reach to the bottom of the page, the `getAllPosts` function should run. my problom is extra rendring dude, do you know why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14271386/peter-park I did it as you say but, i sill have extra rendring.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with **useEffect** second argument.

Your code need refactoring - I suggest separate calls to api into separate functions instead of calling them in UseEffect -> helps to analyze asynchronous code later.

Also 2 calling useEffect isn't good practise.

---

If You remove **getAllPosts** from useEffect - it shouldn't called multiple times - causes an infinity loop

For more information read this article:

https://dev.to/nibble/what-is-useeffect-hook-and-how-do-you-use-it-1p9c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9455902/piotr-%c5%bbak 
Thank you for answering my question, but may you explain more clearly, you mean i should use one useEffect or not at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9455902/piotr-%c5%bbak I changed my code a little, using one `useEffect` and i still have **getAllPosts** in second argument in `useEffect` and nothing happen any infinit loop.

Comment: Hey - it’s also Can rerender because - authContext.userId in first context @mohammad i edit some question about second useEffect argument to precise